# Proof that ℤ^n ( for all n∈ℕ) is countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> [image: Proof (please see image)]

I don't fully understand the proof I have been given for ℤ^n being countable. I'm getting lost at the bit "Let µk : Z^k × Z → Z×Z" onwards. Could anyone maybe try explaining it in a different way please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose we know there is some bijection
$$f:\mathbb{Z}^k\to\mathbb{Z}$$
Now, we can define a bijection
$$g:\mathbb{Z}^{k+1}\to\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$$
as follows: for every $(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_{k+1})\in\mathbb{Z}^{k+1}$, we say that:
$$g(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_{k+1})=(f(a_1,a_2,\ldots ,a_k),a_{k+1})$$
We already have a bijection
$$h:\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$$
So now, $h\circ g$ is a bijection from $\mathbb{Z}^{k+1}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$. So if $\mathbb{Z}^k$ is countable, then $\mathbb{Z}^{k+1}$ is as well.